# CCAvenue integration error code 112 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ccavenue

We are integrating our approved CCAvenue to our ASP.NET site. We want to use iframe integration.
But as we use the url to ccavenue we get an error like

Error Code: 112
Don't worry... It happens to the best of us.

CCAvenue seems to have very poor documentation for integration. We couldn't find a page on their site where meanings of these error codes has been listed.

If anybody has previously done integration and can help us, we would be thankful.

Awaiting response from experts
Regards
Anshul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I integrated CCAvenue in PHP and i faced same problem. Later i found out that this error was caused because the **Web Store URL** defined in the settings and the URL (it was localhost in my case) i was testing from wasn't same.

You can check **Web Store URL** from the menu Settings->Gateway Settings.

After i tested it from that URL defined in **Web Store URL**, it was successful.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. Yes, that's indeed the case. Besides no matter what URL has been set in your Web Store URL, the test mode doesn't get enabled automatically. You have to repeatedly contact them to make the things work correctly.

Comment: Dont mention it, i already faced their customer support and honestly i didnt face any worse before this. Feeling good to be helpful. Regards.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes, but in my case Web Store URL is empty there is no value there.

Comment: @AthulAK thats maybe another reason for error 112. You have to define Web Store URL first before testing. Let me know.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes, thank you so much, it works now.  in my case i also mistakenly filled $merchant_data with my merchant id.(which is suppose to be empty ie; $merchant_data='';  )